# Apache camel restarting the route

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel

I have a something as following:

```
from("rabbitmq://...")
     .process(processor1)
            :
     .process(processorn)
     .process(SendToExternalAppProcessor)
```

The `SendToExternalAppProcessor.process()` uses producer template to send the some request formed from the contents in the `exchange` parameter to another `rabbitmq2` with `sendBody()` method.

The issue is that once `SendToExternalAppProcessor.process()` executes and above route executes, it restarts above route again along with the listener of the `rabbitmq2`.

What I am missing here? Is there any apache camel configuration that is slipping from my attention?

**PS:** I know I have not given any concrete code here so as to replicate the scenario on your machine, but am in hope that experienced head and eyes will be quick to recall and suggest something. (Also I cannot straightway share my project code and also its big and complex)

**Update:**
I tried by commenting `sendBody()` and still restarts the route. I must be missing something weird basic setting here...

Comment: Can you share any log messages? What is the indication to you that the route is restarting?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a misunderstanding of the way routes work. 'from' is not a one-shot event; it will keep accepting messages from the source until you explicitly tell the route to stop.

Comment: I understand that. I published single message to rabbitmq. Is their any chance that `from()` which was listening on that rabbitmq can run infinitely. I guess it should run only once right for single message published to it?

Comment: Hmmm... maybe the message is a InOut exchange type and it is going back to the 'from' endpoint? Maybe enable message tracing and see. You could also add:
.setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly)
just after 'from' to force it and see if that changes behavior.

Answer (score 0):

"from " works as a normal rabbitmq consumer. The route is designed as always running.

If you just want to transfer exchanges to another rabbitmq , "to" is enough.

```
from("rabbitmq://...")
     .process(processor1)
            :
     .process(processorn)
     .to("rabbitmq://rabbit2...")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please let us know which version of Camel you are using. 
Are you using transacted camel flow? If any transaction mode is on then one possible issue could be JMS commit acknowledgment. May be Camel is consuming message and processing but not acknowledging rabbitmq. So message is still there and consuming again and again by camel route. By default it is AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE, so that should not be the case if not transacted camel route.